# the closest thing to

Tags: meaning, sentence

> ​This summer we are running week-long series focusing on a single subject. Here, in the first article on travel and tourism, we assess the sector’s overall state of health
>
> **It is the closest thing to an industry banker**. In recent decades the global travel sector has grown, on average, one percentage point faster than GDP every year. In 2017 travel and tourism accounted for around a tenth of global GDP and employment. That is testament to its resilience. Blips, caused by terrorism or recession, tend to be quickly overcome. Even a destination hit by a significant terrorist incident can expect tourist levels to return to normal in about a year. The industry also has demographics on its side. While many sectors fret relentlessly about millennials, the ageing populations of Europe, America and China should boost travel firms; older people, with more money and spare time, are keen globetrotters. And in China they still have a huge potential market. Bernstein, a research house, reckons the Chinese will provide $400bn of extra tourism revenue by 2025—perhaps the largest opportunity of any segment of any industry.

Does it mean the assessment is something similiar to what an industry banker would do?

Comment: Only as a safe place to store money, with a good chance of gaining value.

Comment: sorry, I don't get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from an article by an investment journalist.

First, he gives statistics to show that this is a growth sector (faster than GDP). It is large(accounting for a tenth of GDP and employment). The sector is stable.

To summarise,, this is a safe investment, a safe place to put your money (always supposing you have any).

**'A banker'** is race-course slang for a sure bet. **'An industry banker'** is a financial 'sure bet,' a safe investment.

> Banker ([LEXICO on-line dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/banker))
>   2. *British* A supposedly certain bet.
>   ‘the horse should be a banker for him in the Members' race’